# Blank arguments in Drupal view not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm stuck on (what I think is) a simple views issue.

I have a view with a page display, with a path of:
/mydir/%/%

Some URLs I would hit are:
/mydir/pc/2008/
/mydir/xbox/2007/
/mydir/pc/

%1 and %2 are different CCK fields. When I specify the path with both arguments:
/mydir/pc/2008/
it works great. But the one argument paths:
/mydir/pc/
/mydir/xbox
aren't working at all. I get a 404 page not found (and I did not select the 404 option in my view).

The breadcrumb links on this page:
/mydir/pc/2008/
link to 
/mydir/pc/*
which just outputs a * to the screen. Sometimes I've been able to configure it to output all the right stuff with
/mydir/pc/*
but I don't want the * there, I just want
/mydir/pc/

I tweaked all of the argument settings for each argument in every way possible I can imagine, and I can't get my desired behavior, which is that this URL:
/mydir/pc/
just ignores or uses any match for the second argument and matches the first.

Also odd: The preview tool in the view works correctly, if I pass in just pc/ in the arguments box. The URL that is outputted in the views preview ouput is also correct: /mydir/pc/. But if I click on that (after saving), I still get the 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. My path setting for the page display on the view was:
apocalypse/%/%
but should have been
apocalypse/%